# Cookies alert to only show at first visit (code syntax issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a cookies alert to show only once to "new" visitors. I combined the jquery with a "dismiss alert" code. (1) The "notification show" and (2) the "dismiss alert" does not want to work? I suspect a problem with my code syntax.
FIDDLE...[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/018gpjzo/6/)

HTML

```
<div class="notification-bar" id="ageNotification">
    <div class="cookies-text">
        <p>Cookies text!!!!!</p>
    </div>  
    <div class="close dismissbar" data-dismiss="notification">&times;</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.cookie("pop") == null) {
        $("#ageNotification").notification("show");
        $.cookie("pop", "2");
    }
});
$(".dismissbar").click(function() {
$(".notification-bar").hide();
});
});
```

Comment: please add fiddle in ur post

Comment: @Alex - added Fiddle to post

Answer (score 1):

i am using this code to show facebook like box only once per week and it works great.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if($.cookie('popup_user_login') != 'yes'){
$('#fanback').delay(1000).fadeIn('medium');
$('#Burp, #fan-exit').click(function(){
$('#fanback').stop().fadeOut('medium');
$.cookie('popup_user_login', 'yes', { path: '/', expires: 7 });
});
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if the cookie is set and then do the rest:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof $.cookie("pop") == 'undefined') {
        $("#ageNotification").show();
        $.cookie("pop", "2");
    }
    else{
        $("#ageNotification").hide();
    }
    $(".dismissbar").click(function() {
        $(".notification-bar").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($.cookie("pop") == null) {

        $("#ageNotification").notification("show");
        $.cookie("pop", "2");

        $(".dismissbar").click(function () {
             $(".notification-bar").hide();
        });

    } else {

       $("#ageNotification").notification("hide");
   }           

});
```